# Application stop unexpectedly. ForceClose Error

Tags: android, android-activity

Can't start activity from main activity.
In main activity, i have to buttons.
After clicking them, I intent to launch respective activity like this;

```
final Intent entryIntent = new Intent(this,PolicyEntry.class);
    final Intent retrieveIntent = new Intent(this,ViewPolicy.class);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(entryIntent);
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(retrieveIntent);
        }
    });
```

PolicyEntry and ViewPolicy are declared in manifest like this:

```
 <activity android:name=".ACDroid" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".PolicyEntry" android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ViewPolicy" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

But whenever I click those buttons:

> The application (process com...) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again error shows.

In addition, in the Logcat, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class com.acdroid....   error occurs.
What do I do?

[image: Logcat error]

Comment: Did you try to add the real packege path for example: com.you.PolicyEntry ?

Comment: can you put the logcat trace as it is?

Comment: >>PravinCG   I have added logcat screenshot.

Comment: How many activities are in the project? only the policyentry and the viewpolicy?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the package in manifest, like

```
<activity android:name="your_package_here.PolicyEntry" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and then hit Project->Clean and then run the project again.

Comment: added package name in manifest and button continues. But I wonder why? I never used to declare activity with package name, and it usually works.

Answer (score 0):

After you declare and assign the intent, set the flag value:

```
entryIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
retrieveIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in PolicyEntry and ViewPolicy Activity.Please check onCreate method of these Activity